# How is the default user given sudo access without being listed in sudoers?

Tags: sudo

I have a question about command `sudo`.

Basically, you know, `sudo` allows any permitted users who enrolled in the `/etc/sudoers` to perform some commands specified in it.

At this point, I wonder how my default user account can use `sudo`.

The following is content of my `/etc/sudoers` file.

```
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

As you see, my account - `jwl` - is not registered in that file. But I can use `sudo` command without any problems. How can it be possible? Is there any mechanism I don't know? If so, let me know it.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your account was created during installation, it will be part of the `sudo` group, and the `sudo` group is mentioned in that file (the line with `%sudo`). You can confirm this by running the `groups` command, which lists the groups your user is a member of.

Comment: Wow,I confirmed it with groups command and referred to /etc/passwd file. As you told, my account is member of sudo groups. Thank you for your help :)